# Solvable algebraic groups and base-change

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be an algebraic group over a field $k$ of characteristic zero. My understanding is that solvability is not a geometric property (is this correct though?).
This motivates my questions:

> Let $K/k$ be a finite extension. Suppose $G$ is solvable. Is $G_K$ still solvable? What about when $K = \bar{k}$?

Conversely,

> If $G_{\bar{k}}$ is solvable, does this imply that $G$ is solvable?

Comment: What's your definition of solvable? For me, $G$ is solvable if its derived series $\mathcal{D}^kG$ terminates. But, $\mathcal{D}^k(G_\ell)=(\mathcal{D}^k G)_\ell$ for all extensions $\ell/k$. Doesn't that answer your question?

Comment: @AlexYoucis Same definition. Does this solve the second question as well?

Comment: @AlexYoucis Also, if you provide a reference for what you said and write it in an answer, I'll accept your answer